# What is the proper use of Jquery's $get to retrieve a control

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

How might I reference a control in JQuery so that it wont throw an error if the control doesnt exist?

ie: this at the moment throws server error in asp.net

```
if ($get('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>') != null) {   <-- Fails with "The name 'Panel1' does not exist in the current context"
  $get('<%= Panel1.ClientID %>').scrollTop = yPos;
}
```

which is present in a master page, but for certain content pages will exist, in those cases I have code to reset the scroll position.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a server-side issue, not jQuery.   `Panel1.ClientID` is evaluated on the server-side while the page is being generated.

Also, the jQuery you need is `$('#<%= Panel1.ClientID %>')`

Answer (score 1):

You could assign this panel some CSS class and then use a CSS selector in jQuery:

```
$('.someClassNameOfThePanel').scrollTop(yPos);
```

and on the server the Panel could look like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="someClassNameOfThePanel">
    ...
</asp:Panel>
```